# Suitescript2.0 Saved Search how to reference another table

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I am trying to get value from another type.
My main saved search type is "transaction", and I've got a custom record type which is "inboundshipment".
When I tried to make Transaction saved search, I couldn't see fields of "inboundshipment". But obviously, those either types have same value which is "PO". I know those field names are different, but values are same.
Here is the thing I want to show up 'externaldocumentnumber' in "transaction" type which has same PO with "inboundshipment" type.

```
var po = 'tranid'
var mySearch = search.create({
                type: "transaction",
                columns: [
                    search.createColumn({
                        name: 'externaldocumentnumber', //Container#
                        join: 'inboundshipment'
                    }),
                search.createColumn({
                    name: 'purchaseorder', //PO
                    join: 'inboundshipment'
                }),
                ],
                filters: [
                    search.createFilter(
                        {
                            name: 'purchaseorder', //PO
                            join: 'inboundshipment',
                        operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
                        values: po
                            }
                        ),
                    search.createFilter(
                        {
                            name: po //PO
                            operator: search.Operator.NONEOF,
                            values: ['@NONE@']
                        }
                  ),
                ]
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a new feature in NetSuite called SuiteQL, it is NS query language which is based on SQL-92. You can perform joins that is not possible in Saved Search. At the moment SuiteQL is available using the N/query module and still in beta in REST web service.

Below is a sample usage of SuiteQL:

```
var suiteQL = "SELECT * FROM transactions t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE id = t.id UNION SELECT -1 FROM transactions)"
var resultIterator = query.runSuiteQLPaged({
    query: suiteQL,
    pageSize: 10
}).iterator()
resultIterator.each(function(page) {
    var pageIterator = page.value.data.iterator();
    pageIterator.each(function(row) {
        log.debug('ID: ' + row.value.getValue(0) + ', Context: ' + row.value.getValue(1));
        return true;
    });

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Netsuite does not do SQL style joins on values. The only types of join that Netsuite does using N/search is when one record type is related to another via a List/Record or Multi-Select type field.

You can set that custom field up on your custom record or on the transaction. In either scenario the join value would be the scripting id of the list/record custom field.

Comment: Oh... okay, I added a record type of Transaction, put values in. But this takes too long time. Is this the only way to get values which has no references from other types?